# How can I read a line of numbers from a file into a list?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a .in file with the first line of data "3 59 98" and the second line of data "8 52 77 45".

I'm trying to read each line of integers into a list.  I already understand how to make a list and put numbers in the list.  What I am having trouble with is how to get the first line of numbers into a list object.

the following is an idea of what I have so far:

```
// in is a filestream object
int a
while (in >> a)
{
     integer_list.push_back(a);
}
```

I know this doesn't work because it puts both lines of numbers into one list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No more duplicates. This has been answered a hundred times already. Please don't post answers to this.

Comment: @KerrekSB I removed my answer. Maybe we should try to edit the original so that it is easier to find?

Comment: How do I close this question?

Comment: @Brandon: don't worry, once enough people vote it as a duplicate, it'll be closed automatically. You can leave it around, though, so that when people search for it they'll be directed one of the other questions.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: I think there are at least 20 "originals" of this. I just selected one I rememebered, but it'd be easy to find many others. We don't really have a "canonical answer" section...

Answer (score 1):

Use [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a whole line and then create `std::istringstream` from this line. Read from the `std::istringstream` the numbers in the list just as if you are reading from a file stream.

Answer (score -2):

What you need to do is to create a list of integer lists, although in C++ you would prefer to use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > list_of_integer_lists;
```

then for each line you would add a new list or vector.

```
list_of_integer_lists.push_back( std::vector<int>() );
```

and for each line you add the numbers to the last list.

```
list_of_integer_lists.back().push_back( number );
```